How to calculate correctly the number of IPs needed when there are multiple workers?
I have the following Azure resources
2 subnets - Subnet A & subnet B
11 web apps with 3 workers each. Each web app is vnet integrated in subnet A with private endpoints in subnet B.
5 functions with  3 workers and also each function is vnet integrated in subnet A with private endpoints in subnet B (in the same service plan as webapps).
and 2 VMs vnet integrated in subnet A.
IPs in Subnet B = number of private endpoints = 5 + 11 IPs
IPs in Subnet A = number of web resources x workers + VMs = 33 + 15 + 2 IPs
Are my assumptions correct?

Subnet A
Web Apps: 11 web apps, each with 3 workers. So, total IPs needed: 11×3=33
Functions: 5 functions, each with 3 workers. So, total IPs needed: 5×3=15
VMs: 2 VMs, so total IPs needed: 2.
Total IPs required for Subnet A: 33+15+2=50

Subnet B
Web Apps: 11 private endpoints.
Functions: 5 private endpoints.
Total IPs needed for private endpoints: 11+5=16.
Subnet A: Requires 50 IPs (for web apps, functions, and VMs).
Subnet B: Requires 16 IPs (for private endpoints).

Yes, your assumption is correct. Here is a detailed explanation of the requirement.
Let assume under Subnet A you have a virtual network configured with web apps, functions, and VMs and under Subnet B you have private endpoints for web apps and function apps.
Therefore your Subnet A IP Calculation:
Web Apps: 11 web apps, each with 3 workers. So, total IPs required 11×3=33
Functions: 5 function apps, each with 3 workers. So, total IPs required: 5×3=15
VMs: 2 VMs, so total IPs required: 2.
Finally, IPs required for Subnet A: 33+15+2=50
Subnet B IP Calculation:
Private Endpoints: Each web app and function app has a private endpoint in Subnet B.
Web Apps: 11 private endpoints.
Functions: 5 private endpoints.
Finally, IP's required for Subnet B: 11+5=16
You may require 50 IPs (for web apps, functions, and VMs) for Subnet A and 16 IPs (for private endpoints) for Subnet B:
